# Bootstrap input border flashing when clicking away from altered input:focus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple form with an input field where I created my own floating placeholder/label. I then wanted to change how the focus behave, removing shadow and alter the borders. Here is the code I have right now which is almost working:

```css
.paddings{
  padding: 5rem;
}
input.my-input:focus{
  box-shadow: none;
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 100, 173, 0.5);
  border-top: none;
}
.floating-label{
  color: rgb(80 80 80);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
input:focus ~ .floating-label{
  color: rgb(40 40 40);
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  top: -0.65rem;
  left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row paddings">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div>
      <input class="form-control my-input" type="text"> 
      <span class="floating-label">Search</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All looks good when focusing on the element. However, when I unfocus there is a flash of black top border for some reason. Why is this happeneing?

I tried to remove the transition but it is still there. How can I make it transition back to the light grey color it was without the top border flashing black in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the `border-top` property on `input.my-input:focus` being set to `none`. Removing that and adjusting the negative margin on `input:focus ~ .floating-label` should fix it:

Edit: In response to OP's comment - changing the color of the `border-top` property will resolve the issue:

```css
.paddings{
  padding: 5rem;
}
input.my-input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 100, 173, 0.5);
  border-top: whitesmoke;
  
}
.floating-label{
  color: rgb(80 80 80);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
input:focus ~ .floating-label {
  color: rgb(40 40 40);
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  top: -0.65rem;
  left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row paddings">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div>
      <input class="form-control my-input" type="text"> 
      <span class="floating-label">Search</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting the border top to none is part of my styling, I don't want a top border. It is in the way of the text, that is why I remove it. And I don't want the text to be so far up.

Comment: Try changing the color of the border-top property, that should work. Edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I put it as transparent but it has the same effect.